# Why some HTTP/HTTPS randomly starts with 1|X?

Tags: tomcat, networking, browser, atmosphere

In the last month i've received a lot of reports from users who encountered strange problems with the web application; while investigating those segnalations i noticed that all the problems were caused due to a random request that received a response starting with **1|X**.

Since i remembered that a similar problem occurred to one of ours client due to an incorret setting of the reverse proxy on Tomcat, i suggested to check all the setting and their response was that all the configurations are correct; personally speaking i was dubious that they checked everything, so i suggested to check for firewall until starting from last Friday (26/04) i've encountered the same problem on my local workspace where i know that everything is correctly configured (and there are no firewall on localhost).

A strange thing about this problem is that it seems to add those three characters randomly (**always** those three characters!); up until now i've seen only *.js* and *.html* failing response.

If the failed call is repeated or the page is refreshed, then it will return a correct response (although the second option could lead to another call to fail...).

An example of the error, occurred while loading angular.js
[image: An example of the error, occurred while loading angular.js]

I really don't know what can cause this problem, and due to this i don't know what could be helpful so i'll put here a few specs that maybe could be usefull:

- Tomcat 7.x (usually 7.0.59 or 7.0.82)
- Java JDK 8u202
- Atmosphere 2.6.1

Let me know if you need something more specific.

EDIT: it seems that the **1|X** it's an Atmosphere [HearthBeatInterceptor](http://async-io.org/apidocs/) message, generated from the default initialization of the field [paddingBytest](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/blob/4eb90b8c2d73bc18cfe3b1f897c1d6e3aa0d318e/modules/cpr/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/interceptor/HeartbeatInterceptor.java).

The Atmosphere message response has the following structure:

- lenght of the message
- separator (pipe)
- real message

So, as show in the following image, sometimes Atmosphere make an HeartBeat message using the charater **X**.
[image]

Now the question is why sometimes those HeartBeat messages are merged to other response.

Comment: You are using a truly ancient version of Tomcat, even for Tomcat 7. 7.0.82 is almost 4 years old, while 7.0.59 is more than _6_ years old. Are you able to test with a more recent version? 7.0.109 was released two days ago...